# Output disappeared Javascript simple innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, output

I am new to javascript and on every simple thing i get some kind of problem but this seems un-solve-able to me. I googled and nothing simillar.

After i input data into textbox and store it into variable, i print out variable in paragraph.
Problem is that output i printed out disappears within less than second. Code seems to be normal, what might it be? It looks like c when you dont put getch();
 Thanks in advance.

```
<form>Unesite broj koji ce se ispisat kasnije.<br>
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="submit" name="unos" value="Unesi i ispisi" onclick="unesi()"><br><br>

</form> 
    <br><br>
<p>Unjeli ste <b id="ispis"></b></p>
<script>
function unesi(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
document.getElementById('ispis').innerHTML = userInput;
}   

</script>
```

Comment: You are submitting the form with the button, try changing type from 'submit' to 'button'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<form>` tag doesn't specify an `action` attribute, so when you click the submit button, the browser will submit the form to the current URL - which will look a lot like the page is refreshing.

If you want to run the `unesi` function when the user clicks submit and prevent the HTML form from submitting, you need to change it slightly:

```
<input type="submit" name="unos" value="Unesi i ispisi"
      onclick="unesi(); return false;">
```

The `return false` prevents the form from submitting itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i understand now,and i would not withouth ur explanation. But ur code doesnt do any good its still refresh. Only working thing is removing <form> from code.

Answer (score 3):

Because the form submits and refreshes the page. Cancel the form request.

```
<input type="submit" name="unos" value="Unesi i ispisi" onclick="return unesi()">
```

and the function

```
function unesi(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('ispis').innerHTML = userInput;
    return false;
}
```

better option is to do it on the form level

```
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return unesi()">
```

Comment: I did your first option and  still it gets refreshed, as well as second...
only thing working was removing <form> from code.
thanks a lot i would not understand it without ur help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cancelling the form submitting, another option is to change

```
<input type="submit" name="unos" value="Unesi i ispisi" onclick="unesi()">
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="unos" value="Unesi i ispisi" onclick="unesi()">
```

This will make it so the form does not try to submit at all when the button is pressed.